# method that will return true if there is no digit in code

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

```
 package code;
 public class WriteUp{

 public boolean containsNoDigits(String s){
    s  = s.toLowerCase();
    char[] n = {'0', '1', '2', ....., '9'} //i wrote out 0-9
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (c == n[i]);
                  return false; //if string contain digit
    }
    return true; //if string contain NO digit
 }
 }
```

I want to write a method (using Array) to check if my string contain a digit or not. digit => false; no digit => true;

my code fail to pass both the JUnit test

JUnit Test:

```
  @Test
  public void test(){
        code.WriteUp wu = new code.WriteUp();
        boolean expected = true;
        boolean actual = wu.containsNoDigits("there is no digit")
        assertTrue("", expected ==actual);
  }

  @Test
  public void test01(){
        code.WriteUp wu = new code.WriteUp();
        boolean expected = false;
        boolean actual = wu.containsNoDigits("there are digit, 0342432")
        assertTrue("", expected ==actual);
  }
```

How can I fix the code so that it will work correctly

Comment: Remove that semicolon from `if (c == n[i]);`.

Comment: You're probably best off using [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Your asserts should probably be `assertTrue("False positive for digit", actual)` and `assertFalse("Failed to detect digit", actual)`. Remember, when the tests fail, you'll see that message. The empty string doesn't tell you anything. Also, I would name the methods something like `shouldNotFindDigits` and `shouldFindDigits`, which not only documents  what you're testing for, but will also help to document the meaning of a failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading my code again carefully i was able to know why i messed up and figure out a solution.

```
   public boolean containsNoDigits(String s) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    char[] n = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c == n[0] || c == n[1] || c == n[2] || c == n[3] || c == n[4] || 
                c == n[5] || c == n[6] || c == n[7] ||  c == n[8] || c == n[9]) {
            return false; // if s has no digit
        }
    }
    return true; // if s has digit
}
```

thank you for providing shorter and more efficient solution. I am a beginner therefore i was writing my code as basic as possible, this solution was so that i can have a better understanding for using array.

Answer (score 4):

The semicolon terminates the block, remove it

```
if (c == n[i]); // <-- here
    return false;
```

is actually

```
if (c == n[i]); // <-- here
return false;
```

You need something like (with braces preferably)

```
if (c == n[i]) {
    return false;
}
```

or

```
if (c == n[i])
    return false;
```

Also, a regular expression would be more efficient. Like

```
public boolean containsNoDigits(String s){
    return !s.matches("\\d"); // <-- digit pattern
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public boolean hasDigit(String x){
    for (char c : x.toCharArray())
        if (Character.isDigit(c))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

You can use a **character array** to effortlessly loop through all characters in the string and use the function **Character.isDigit(c)** to easily check each character. This is likely the most simple and easiest to read.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Java's Character class contains a static method that will check weather a character is a digit. `Character.isDigit(char ch)` will do this for you.

You code using this method could be

```
public boolean hasNoDigits(String s){
   for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
       if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))){
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

---

If you only want the method to return false if the string contains standard latin digits , `0 through 9` (`\u0030` through `\u0039`), your code could be modified to be this:

```
public boolean hasNoDigits(String s){
   for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
       char atIndex=s.charAt(i);
       if(atIndex >= '0' && atIndex <= '9'){
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

The reason for this change is that `Character.isDigit(char ch)` returns true on all characters that are classified by Unicode to be digits.

> Some Unicode character ranges that contain digits:
>
> - '\u0030' through '\u0039', ISO-LATIN-1 digits ('0' through '9')
> - '\u0660' through '\u0669', Arabic-Indic digits
> - '\u06F0' through '\u06F9', Extended Arabic-Indic digits
> - '\u0966' through '\u096F', Devanagari digits
> - '\uFF10' through '\uFF19', Fullwidth digits

What this means is that a string containing this `昍` or this `०` would return true.

Comment: Did you not see my answer? It is exactly the same except that you don't use a character loop. Copying other people's code isn't at all helpful.

Comment: @lacraig2 If you are the one who down-voted me, please consider that I created and posted this answer without being aware that your answer existed and without any malicious intent. While the presence of your answer does make mine superfluous, it is by no means a valid reason to down-vote.

Comment: @lacraig2 If it makes you feel any better, I edited my answer to contain information that yours does not.

Comment: do you know why that if i do  
  atIndex >= '0' && atIndex <= '9' 
it would work but if i was to switch it to
atIndex >= 'a' && atIndex <= 'z' and switch the return for true and false it wouldn't work?

Comment: @TKLE I can't say exactly what problem your having, but `atIndex >= 'a' && atIndex <= 'z'` only returns true for lower case letters.